# jQuery flot plot with dynamically changing barWidth

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, flot

I am plotting a dynamic barchart using flot. I have managed to plot with constant barwidth. Now I want the barwidth to vary based on the output of my analysis. I set 
`var options = { series: {
                bars:{show:true,
                barWidth: BarWidth,
                fillColor: "lightgreen",
             fill: true
                }` In this code, `BarWidth` is a javascript variable. My bar starts to plot and gets overlapped when my BarWidth changes. 
Does anyone has any clue how I can solve my problem?

Thank you in advance!

Sample my code is below:

```
function plot_status(statusData, no_strips) {
    new_data = new_data.concat([statusData]);

    var options = {
        series: {
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: no_strips * 72,
                fillColor: "lightgreen",
                fill: true
            }
        },
        grid: {
            clickable: true,
            hoverable: true,
            borderWidth: 1
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {

        chart1 = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [{
            data: new_data,
            threshold: {
                below: 0,
                color: "red"
            },
            color: "black",
            xaxis: {
                ticks: 8,
                minTickSize: 1
            },
            yaxis: {
                min: -1,
                max: 3,
                tickSize: 1
            },
            grid: {
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        }], options)

    });
};
```

Every four seconds, `statusData` and `no_strips` change. new_data contains a series of data that is plotted. The barchar grows with time as long as statusData is concatenated to new_data. `no_strips` determine the barWidth of each plot of the barchart. I will also include sample of barchart I would like to produce.

With a constant `barWidth` this is what I produce

[image: This is a bar chart with 1200 <code>barWidth</code>]

This is my data: `[[0, 1], [1200, 1], [2400, -1], [3600, 1], ... ];` rather I was sending it for my above plot.

This is the the data I want to plot [[0, 1], [72, 1], [144, -1], [432, 1],[504,1],...]`every`[a,b]`  is added every four seconds.

Comment: I have asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147081/how-to-change-the-constant-barwidth-in-jquery-flot-bar-char-to-variable-barwidth   a couple of days ago. I am asking again since I didnt get any answer after I edited the question.

Comment: I edited your code because you were missing a closing bracket. But make sure whether it's correct. You call the ready() function in your original function? Or are they two separate function blocks? It was a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @Antonis, thanks for the edit. You are right. I missed the closing bracket. ready() function is in plot_status() function.

Comment: No problem. I'll try to give you a solution later, when I have free time.

Comment: First of all, you don't need the ΄$(document).ready()΄ wrap to yout chart making. the ready() is only called when the DOM is fully loaded ( http://api.jquery.com/ready/ ). So try first to remove this wrap.

There not a lot I can tell you with this code. You use some library for making this graph ( you call $.plot() ), so this is where you need to see if variable width is supported. Can you make a working jsFiddle example? It would help a lot. You can load there any external library is needed to show your example.